# How to get my ad banner to appear over my app without taking the entire app away?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, banner

I am using the example code found here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

My problem is that the ads are showing up, but now my app wont work. My display is exactly like the picture shown in the linked page. The ad shows, and it works, but now thats it: the ad and empty space.

What could I be doing wrong?

AndroidManifest

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

layout - main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/adBanner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java (the main class in my android package)

```
package com.google.android.gms.ads.banner;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import -omitted-
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import -omitted-

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
  /** The view to show the ad. */
  private AdView adView;

  /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1350996374659154/6187192628";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;

    initialize(new Beacon(), cfg);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("BA806B06E9FDE5DEDF704F86521731EC")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

  }
  }
```

Comment: You should probably remove "eclipse" from your list of tags as this issue has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You have called **setContentView(R.layout.main);** with a blank layout in which you have added  an AdView. I would expect it to show an AdView and nothing more which is exactly what it is doing.

What you haven't said is that you are also using libgdx and have made a call to the libgdx method AndroidApplication#initialize which also sets the Activity ContentView. You should ony call #setCOntentView once.

If you want to use libgdx and also include other elements (such as an AdView) in your layout then you need to find a libgdx method that plays better with others.